# How can I count unique pairs of values in SQL?

Tags: sql, count

With the following sql statement I can get all unique values with their counts for a given column:

```
select column, count(column) as count 
         from table group by column order by count desc;
```

How would I get all unique pairs of values with counts.  For instance if I had a table of with columns first_name and last_name, I might find results something like this:

> first_name   |   last_name   |   count
>
> John   |  Smith  |   42
>
> John   |   Johnson  | 39
>
> David  |  Smith  |  37

etc...

Can I do this in basic SQL?  I generally use MySQL, but I assume whatever solution you come up with should be translatable to any db.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You've almost got it correct... You just add an additional `GROUP BY` column like so:

```
SELECT [first_name], [last_name], COUNT(*) AS [Count] 
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY [first_name], [last_name]
ORDER BY [Count] DESC;
```

Answer (score 23):

If you just want the count of how many distinct pairs, you could do this more simply.
A `GROUP BY` clause is not necessary.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT first_name, last_name) AS count_names FROM Table
```

Comment: This is not valid in PostgreSQL at least.

Comment: For DB2, this query works `SELECT COUNT(*) from (SELECT distinct first_name,last_name FROM Table)`

Comment: This works with postgres: select COUNT(distinct p.id) from Pet p..

Comment: in which dialect?

Answer (score 11):

Use multiple columns in your group by clause.

```
select first_name, last_name, count(*) as count from table group by first_name, last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, COUNT(distinct last_name) AS c
FROM ttable
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
HAVING c > 999
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Adding distinct will do it in MYSQL.
Thanks

Comment: `HAVING` may require the aggregation instead of the alias, ie `HAVING COUNT(...) > 999`